# Switch between nodes/peers in Mist wallet

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, ethereum-wallet-dapp

[image]
I'm new to ethereum and i'm facing this issue. I've created multiple nodes and add them as peers using geth console and can make transactions and stuff from there only. But on installing mist wallet it just shows one of the nodes and accounts in it. It shows others as peers as you can see "2 peers" but there is no option to operate on them from UI. Any suggestions on how I can operate on accounts in other nodes using mist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start multiple instances of Ethereum Wallet. However, you'll have to do it via command line. There you can specify the node to connect with (via IPC or RPC).

```
./Mist --help
...
  --rpc                   Path to node IPC socket file OR HTTP RPC hostport (if
                          IPC socket file then --node-ipcpath will be set with
                          this value).                                  [string]
...
```